# How to set APP_PLATFORM when build android .so library?

Tags: bazel

How to set `APP_PLATFORM` for build android ndk library, just like in `jni/Application.mk`:

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your WORKSPACE file, add the `api_level` attribute:

```
android_ndk_repository(
    name = "androidndk",
    api_level = 17,
)
```